# The Call In Leadership and Literature

Tags: character-analysis

Some of the greatest books I have ever read are in the Book of the Dun Cow novel series, where the main character is a rooster in charge who keeps time in the barnyard through his canonical hour crows - each crow being named something like Vespers, Compline, Matins, etc. which I believe are prayer times in the old Catholic tradition.

And recently I just finished Lord of the Flies, where Ralph is chosen as leader because he is able to blow on a conch shell loud enough to be heard and assemble the scattered children throughout the island.

And it made me think that these individuals weren't established as leaders because of their strength or their brains or any other kind of competitive edge.  They were established more-or-less because they were loud enough to be heard, and because they possessed a fair degree of organizational skills.

Is this determination of leadership a recurring theme in literature?  Are there any other works with leadership being determined in a similar manner?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Literature Stack Exchange. Unfortunately, open ended recommendation requests (e.g., asking for a list of books sharing a certain theme) is off-topic for this site. Please see [these](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1560/289) meta [discussions](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2/289) for the reasoning. Apologies!

Comment: Also, you might want to think more deeply about what you're actually asking. What does it mean to be a recurring theme? If it happens more than twice? What literature? Fifth century Athenian literature? 20th century US-UK literature? You should think a bit about what you're actually asking and whether it's actually significant enough to be discussed. (I.e. why are you making brains and brawn alone as types of leadership traits?). Then I think you might discover an interesting question lying underneath.